# Hierarchical event forwarding in Tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

suppose I have the following Widget hierarchy:

```
set Frame  [frame .f -relief flat]
set Button [button .f.b1]
```

In addition, if I would like to emulate a `button` widget's `-overrelief` by doing the following:

```
# When the mouse hovers over Frame
bind $Frame <Enter> "$Frame configure -relief groove"

# When it exits
bind $Frame <Leave> "$Frame configure -relief flat"
```

The problem becomes that `$Button` somehow breaks this "chain of propagation", i.e. the `<Enter>` event does ***not*** reach `$Frame`. Is there a remedy or is this inherent Tk behavior?

EDIT:

The above example works if the (Mouse) pointer touches the outer border and then triggers `<Enter>` event, but the issue ***remains***, the following modification to the code illustrates this best:

```
#When the pointer is inside the frame widget, print x,y (as relative to the widget)
bind .f <Motion> {puts {%x %y}}
```

`puts` gets called only when the pointer is on the ***edges*** of the frame, ***not inside*** the frame itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the issue you claim. When my mouse pointer enters the button (even coming from another window that partly covers the Tk GUI so the pointer never touches the frame), I get an <Enter> event on both the frame and the button.

Using your example code, the relief change is not visible because a frame has a default borderwidth of 0. So you would need to specify a borderwidth of 2 or so.

Here's a complete script that works for me as you seem to want:

```
set Frame  [frame .f -relief flat -borderwidth 2]
set Button [button .f.b1]
grid $Frame
grid $Button

# When the mouse hovers over Frame
bind $Frame <Enter> [list $Frame configure -relief groove]

# When it exits
bind $Frame <Leave> [list $Frame configure -relief flat]
```

The <Motion> event indeed doesn't get reported to the frame. If you want that to happen too, you can add the frame to the bindtags of the button:

```
bindtags $Button [linsert [bindtags $Button] 1 $Frame]
```

That will make any event on the button to also trigger the frame bindings, unless specifically prevented by button bindings.

With this in place, the <Enter> and <Leave> events of the frame actually trigger twice when entering the button directly. Once because of the event on the frame iteself, and another time due to the bindtags of the button.

Comment: Thanks, indeed the solution is to use `bindtags` to (read and) modify the widget's _binding tags_. If I understood doc correctly, the closest Tk equivalent to _event propagation_ are the _binding tags_. **Each window [has] a list of binding tags that determine how events are processed ... When an event occurs in a window, it's applied to each of the window's tags in order [to match the tag and event]** . So to make `.f` eligible to receive `<Motion>` from`.f.b1` **1)**  the _binding tags_ of `.f.b1` are modified as e.g. `.f.b1 bindtags [list .f.b1 Button .f . all]` **2)** `bind .f <Motion>..`

Comment: Right. But that shouldn't be necessary for Enter and Leave events. As the `bind` manual page explains: In addition, when the pointer moves between two windows, Enter and Leave “virtual crossing” events are sent to intermediate windows in the hierarchy in the same manner as for FocusIn and FocusOut events.

Comment: I should have better worded my EDIT, for my use a single `bind`ing of `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` on `.f` achieved the desired effect, it was not showing since `-bd` (as you pointed out) was by default set to 0.